# Auto adjust font size for UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

For one of my UITableView, to allow more text or large font size text to fit in the fields, I need to add or adjust font size.

I used a boolean for adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth.  And clipsToBounds=true.  But this does not always work for me, not sure why it's inconsistent, especially when you have bigger font size text to be included.  Any correction?

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let headerView = UIView()
    let headerLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 40, y: 0, width:
        tableView.bounds.size.width, height: tableView.bounds.size.height))
    headerLabel.textColor = UIColor.white
    headerLabel.text = self.tableView(self.tableView, titleForHeaderInSection: section)
    headerLabel.sizeToFit()
    headerLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
    headerLabel.clipsToBounds=true
    headerLabel.numberOfLines=0
    headerLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byTruncatingTail
    headerLabel.minimumScaleFactor = 0.2
    headerView.addSubview(headerLabel)

    return headerView
}
```

Comment: what is your problem exactly? did you read the documentation of [adjustsfontsizetofitwidth](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uilabel/1620546-adjustsfontsizetofitwidth)

Comment: The problem is that you size the label once (too soon BTW), and that's it. So the font will never adjust because the size of the label will never change.

Comment: It might be easier to create a [UITableViewHeaderFooterView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewheaderfooterview) and see the effect in the interface builder

Comment: thanks zombie and rmaddy!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete the following may be?

```
headerLabel.sizeToFit()
```

This will allow to make

```
adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth
```

property working.

Comment: You should also add constraints to the label so it sizes along with the header view.

Answer (score 0):

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")
    if searching {
        cell?.textLabel?.text = searchedLabour[indexPath.row]
        cell?.textLabel?.sizeToFit()
        cell?.textLabel?.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
        cell?.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 2
        cell?.textLabel?.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byTruncatingTail
    } else {
        cell?.textLabel?.text = labourWordsArray[indexPath.row]
        cell?.textLabel?.sizeToFit()
        cell?.textLabel?.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
        cell?.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 2
        cell?.textLabel?.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byTruncatingTail
    }
    return cell!
}
```

Comment: You should [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57247918/edit) your question to add a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) demonstrating the problem.